# One to Many Mapping to JPA Object with Composite Key

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, composite-key

I am trying to figure out how to map an entity with a composite key and has an attribute that is part of a composite key on the joining table.

I have SalesOrderNumber on the parent table and 3 attributes on the child table, one of which is SalesOrderNumber.

For the main table (SalesHeader) I am trying to get the SalesOrder entity using the SalesOrderNumber as the joining column so that when I retrieve the SalesHeader, I have a SalesOrder object as well.

Thanks in advance.

## Database

#### SalesHeader Table

```
ClientKey - PK, int
InvoiceNumber - PK, String
InvoiceBillingDateKey - PK, int
SalesOrderNumber - String, not null
```

#### SalesOrder Table

```
ClientKey - PK, int
SalesOrderNumber - PK, String
SalesOrderCreatedOnDateKey - PK, int
```

## Mappings

#### SalesHeader JPA Object

```
@EmbeddedId
    private FactSalesHeaderKey  factSalesHeaderKey;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)

@JoinColumn(name = "SalesOrderNumber", referencedColumnName="SalesOrderNumber", nullable=false)

private FactSalesOrder factSalesOrder;  <==== TRYING TO SET THIS

public FactSalesOrder getFactSalesOrder() {
    return factSalesOrder;
}

public void setFactSalesOrder(FactSalesOrder factSalesOrder) {
    this.factSalesOrder = factSalesOrder;
}
```

#### SalesOrderKey - Composite PK Object

```
@Embeddable

    public class FactSalesOrderKey implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Column(name="ClientKey")
        private Long  clientKey;
        @Column(name="SalesOrderNumber")
        private String salesOrderNumber;
        @Column(name="SalesOrderCreatedOnDateKey")
        private Long salesOrderCreatedOnDateKey;
    }
```

#### SalesOrder - JPA Object

```
@Entity

    public class FactSalesOrder {

    @EmbeddedId
    private FactSalesOrderKey factSalesOrderKey;
    @Column(name="OverallBillingStatus", nullable = true)
    private Long overallBillingStatus;
    @Column(name="OverallDeliveryStatus", nullable = true)
    private Long overallDeliveryStatus;
    @Column(name="OverallOrderStatus", nullable = true)
    private Long overallOrderStatus;

}
```

Comment: kindly see the update to the answer below

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you asking for One to One or One to Many ? You question title says One to Many but code fragment has One to One annotation. Moreover if you have one to one why would you store them in separate table ? If you have one to many relation then you need a join table.
2. Assuming you have one-to-many relation, then you need a set of referenced objects and a mapped by attribute in the table where you put one to many annotation. On other side, you need to put many-to-one annotation and join-columns annotation containing one join-column annotation for each attribute which is part of composite key in referencing table.

   ```
   public class SalesHeader {
     @EmbeddedId
     private SHKey shKey;
     @OneToMany(mappedBy="salesHeader")
     private Set<SalesOrder> salesOrders;

   }

   public class SalesOrder {
   @EmbeddedId
   private SOKey soKey;
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name="clientKey",referencedColumnName="clientKey"),@JoinColumn(name="invoiceNumber",referencedColumnName="invoiceNumber"),@JoinColumn(name="invoiceBillingDateKey",referencedColumnName="invoiceBillingDateKey")})
   private SalesHeader salesHeader;

   }

   public class SHKey{
    @Column(name="clientKey")
    private Long clientKey;
    @Column(name="invoiceNumber")
    private String InvoiceNumber;
    @Column(name="invoiceBillingDateKey")
    private Long InvoiceBillingDateKey;
   }
   ```

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

I think you can not achieve what you are asking this way. It is required to have all the columns of composite key from referenced table into referring table for one-to-one relationship, then only you can define join column(s). In addition to `ClientKey` and `SalesOrderNumber` ou need to have `SalesOrderCreatedOnDate` attribute in `SalesHeader` table for `salesHeader.getSalesOrder()` kind of call to work. As you are telling that you don't have liberty of database schema change, for achieving this you can write queries for given `salesOrderNumber`

Sample code for one-to-one mapping -

```
  @Entity
  public class SalesHeader implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private SHKey shkey;


@OneToOne
@JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name="clientKey",referencedColumnName="clientKey",updatable = false,insertable = false),@JoinColumn(name="SalesOrderNumber",referencedColumnName="SalesOrderNumber"),@JoinColumn(name="SalesOrderCreatedOnDateKey",referencedColumnName="SalesOrderCreatedOnDateKey",updatable = false,insertable = false)})
private SalesOrder salesOrder;


}

@Entity
public class SalesOrder implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@EmbeddedId
private SOKey sokey;


 }

@Embeddable
public class SHKey implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "clientKey")
private Long clientKey;
@Column(name = "invoiceNumber")
private String InvoiceNumber;
@Column(name = "invoiceBillingDateKey")
private Long InvoiceBillingDateKey;
}

@Embeddable
public class SOKey implements Serializable{

@Column(name = "ClientKey")
private Long clientKey;
@Column(name = "SalesOrderNumber")
private String salesOrderNumber;
@Column(name = "SalesOrderCreatedOnDateKey")
private Long salesOrderCreatedOnDateKey;
}
```

You can achieve what you are asking for using named queries or criteria API.

Comment: THanks, the issue is that I have 1 field on the SalesHeader that I am trying to map to the SalesOrder.  The tables are in our Data Warehouse so dont have a choice on combining entities.

Comment: Could not get that to work.... had an issue related to the Clientkey. Essentially what I am trying to do is get a field from the SalesOrder onto the SalesHeader entity.  The SalesHeader does not have all the info for the composite key on the SalesOrder.  The SalesOrder has ClientKey, SalesOrderNumber, SalesOrderCreatedOnDateKey as the composite key.  I have the SalesOrderNumber on the SalesHeader, but thats it.